# How to get an Array of Objects from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What would be the right way to query a field that is an array of maps.

Currently the structure is

```
Collection1
     Document1
         -papers:                <---- This is an array  
              (0): 
                 -Name:abc
                 -Id:123 
              (1): 
                 -Name:xyz
                 -Id:456
```

And this is my code

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Collection1").document("Document1");
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                       //?? how can I retrieve papers
                }
            }
        });
```

Basically do I retrieve it and cast it as an ArrayList> and then loop through it to create my final ArrayList ?

Or how does it work ?

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) will also help future visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit 13 Aug 2018:**

According to the updated documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), now it is possible to filter data based on array values using `whereArrayContains()` method. A simple example would be:

```
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.whereArrayContains("regions", "west_coast");
```

> This query returns every city document where the regions field is an array that contains west_coast. If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once.

---

As per [official documentation regarding arrays](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, **`it does not support`** querying array members or updating single array elements.

If you only want to get the entire `papers` array you need to iterate over a `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("papers")) {
        Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

But note, even if `papers` object is stored in the database as an array, `entry.getValue()` returns an `ArrayList`, not an `array`.

Comment: You can't query array members meaning you can't do filteration based on member but offcourse you can get all the array members data. Otherwise why are they stored. I was able after I posted the question to get an array of hashmap and then iterates over it to create my array of model. I was hoping there is a shorter way though

Comment: Sorry if I made you confused. Yes, every document in Cloud Firestore is a `Map` so you need to iterate in order to get the array. If you have used a model class, you could call a getArray() method on the model class object. So please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arrayInTheDocument = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> ) documentSnapshot.getData().get("documentName.ArrayName");