# Search for locations in arrays of geopoints Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm able to find locations within firestore documents if those have the next structure:

[image]

But how to perform the same searching, if the JSON has a couple of geopoints? Like this:

[image]

I'm using `geoflutterfire` with `cloud_firestore`.

The code to save locations to the database:

```
final geo = Geoflutterfire();
final startPoint = geo.point(
  latitude: 49.805378,
  longitude: 23.982382,
);
final finishPoint = geo.point(
  latitude: 49.79987621408566,
  longitude: 24.035205183081246,
);
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Drivers').doc('12345').set({
  'location': [startPoint.data, finishPoint.data]
});
```

This code is for getting filtered locations:

```
final drivers = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Drivers');
final geo = Geoflutterfire();
final center = geo.point(
  latitude: 49.79987621408566,
  longitude: 24.035205183081246,
);
final Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream =
    geo.collection(collectionRef: drivers).within(
          center: center,
          radius: 4,
          field: 'location',
          strictMode: true,
        );
stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
  // Always empty if there are arrays of locations.
  print(documentList);
});
```

Comment: Ey, after looking for a while I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101373/how-to-get-an-array-of-objects-from-firestore) that talks about to a similar issue that you have, please let me know if help you with you issue

Comment: @Robertocd_98, it's different thing. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: oh I see, but I have one question, you want to query all the array or just one to get one data from the array, for example the position 0 on the location fields

Comment: @Robertocd_98, it may be all items from the array or just one, if they fit to the specified location.

Comment: can you try query the information like ```drivers = db.collection(u'cities')``` and in the following line you can do this ```query=drivers.where(u'location',u'array_contains',u'center.data')``` and tell me if it works for you ?